# How to implement Roles/Permissions model in a Graph Database?

Tags: graph

I'd like to model a Roles/Permissions solution and I thought a graph database may be a good choice. However, I do have a problem with modeling the graph.
The requirements are:

- There are users, roles, permissions, and resources
- A user may have permissions assigned
- A role is combination of permissions
- A user may have roles assigned
- User/role may be assigned to specific permissions for specific resources. With this, I'd like to say that UserA can Get_Resource on Resource1 only (and cannot for example Resource2,Resource3). Another example may be: User2 can Edit_Card on Card1 or Card2 or Card3.

So to sum up: A user has a given permission only for specific data scope/range.

I was able to come up with the model but it requires having copy of Permission per user - I do not know how to express "has assigned PermissionA in scope of Resource1" without duplication of "Permission vertex".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 A user may have permissions assigned
 A role is combination of permissions 
 A user may have roles assigned
```

This seems overly complex and redundant.  Why not:

```
A role is combination of one or more permissions
A user may have roles assigned
```

---

```
has assigned PermissionA in scope of Resource1
```

Again, you seem to be making things unnecessarily complex. Why not say:

```
   RoleXYZ is PremissionA in scope of Resouce1
   UserA is assigned RoleXYZ
```

---

Bottom line: Do not assign scopes *and* permissions *and* roles to users.  Assign scopes to permissions, permissions to roles, and roles to users.

This means that you will have more permissions and roles, but all your relationships will be simpler.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I was not clear, but in my case ResourceA is an instance of a Resource. Imagine we work in a system that has products, I would like to be able to say that UserA has Edit_Product permission only for Product with id 1. It is like an Azure, where you may be a KeyVaultReader of 2 out of 10 Key Vaults.

Comment: Your description is perfectly clear.  It is your design that is confused.  Please read about database normalization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I provided a design which is not optimal. What I described to you are business requirements, do not get your comment about dB normalization... Especially that I don't want to use a relational dB...

Comment: Why not?  A relational database is ideal for this.

Comment: Well, I was thinking about using a graph db. And the design question was about how to design it in a graph db

Comment: You will find a relational db much easier and more effective.  The correct tool always makes a task go better.